# length of the emptyline is 1 while reading it in sh

Tags: bash, unix

I am reading a file in shell script using while loop.

while doing so,an empty line length seems to be 1. But it doesn't contains spaces,\n\r chars.

what would it be?

I need to skip those line basically while looping.That is my main concern.

Someone Please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share some of your code? How do you read and how do you test length? From my experience, I do get a length 0 for empty line.

Comment: length = ${#line}.. this is the code I am using to get the length...if I echo line an empty line is displayed..if I echo length it is 1..

Comment: Depending on how your empty line is created, you probably still have the newline character.

Comment: okay..But How to check that?

Comment: The length is irrelevant for the moment; how is the value of `line` getting set? You need to show how the problem is actually occurring in your question.

Comment: `while IFS= read -r line
do
if [[ ! -z "$line" ]]
then
  echo $line
fi
done < "$file"`
Inside the if loop I am doing someother functionality.But trying to avoid empty lines..whereas the file I read is the ini file which has an empty line inbetween sections

Comment: Maybe it is not an empty line. Try to print out its binary, `echo $line && echo $line | od -t x1`, `LF` is `0a`

Comment: 0000000 0d 0a
0000002
am getting this while doing as u said Xin

Comment: Thanks Xin and chepner for ur inputs

Comment: `0d 0a` is the `\r\n` line ending. Try converting your file to just LF line endings with `dos2unix` or `sed -i 's/\r$//' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to skip empty lines, why do you want to test for the length?
Just use

```
[[ -z "${line}" ]]
```

to test if the current line is empty

Comment: `if [[ ! -z "$line" ]];
then;
    echo $line;
fi;`

Comment: even empty line gets into this loop and it is printed

Comment: NullDev..You are right..Thanks for ur response..please see my ans for further details

Answer (score 0):

The file I was trying to read was created in windows and moved to unix..and that was the problem itseems...When I trying to read the same file directly created in unix in the same way as windows..empty line is skipped as I expect...Thanks a lot for all ur inputs